# FutureBuilder - setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I have the below FutureBuilder entry.

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: _checkConn,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState){
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, NoConnView);
                      break;
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    case ConnectionState.done:
                      if(snapshot.data=='OK'){
                        initialfbget();
                        break;
                      } else {
                        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, NoConnView);
                        break;
                      }
                  }
                  return SizedBox.expand(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: _vcontroller.value.size?.width ?? (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                        height: _vcontroller.value.size?.height ?? (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                        child: VideoPlayer(_vcontroller),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );

                }
            ),
```

---

The below is the complete initstate section:

```
void initState()  {
    super.initState ();

    _vcontroller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/testimages/sukiitestanimation.mp4")
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Once the video has been loaded we play the video and set looping to true.
        _vcontroller.play();
        _vcontroller.setLooping(false);
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized.
      });

    _checkConn = checkConn();
    Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
```

---

Below is the checkconn segment:

```
Future<String> checkConn() async {
    var connresponse = await http.get(connurl).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    log('connresponse is: ${connresponse.statusCode}');
    if(connresponse.statusCode!=200) {
      return "BAD";
    } else {
      return "OK";
    }
  }
```

---

Kept on receiving the below error.

setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Would appreciate any assistance on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your `checkConn()` and your full `initState()` method? it will help another volunteer to answer this

Comment: ```Future<String> checkConn() async {
    var connresponse = await http.get(connurl).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    log('connresponse is: ${connresponse.statusCode}');
    if(connresponse.statusCode!=200) {
      return "BAD";
    } else {
      return "OK";
    }
  }

Comment: @GilangPratama, re-pasting requested info. `Future<String> checkConn() async {
    var connresponse = await http.get(connurl).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    log('connresponse is: ${connresponse.statusCode}');
    if(connresponse.statusCode!=200) {
      return "BAD";
    } else {
      return "OK";
    }
  }`.

Comment: `void initState()  {   
    super.initState ();   

    _vcontroller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/testimages/sukiitestanimation.mp4")
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Once the video has been loaded we play the video and set looping to true.
        _vcontroller.play();   
        _vcontroller.setLooping(false);   
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized.   
      });
   
    _checkConn = checkConn();   
    Firebase.initializeApp();   


  }`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know what is `_checkConn = checkConn();` in your `initState()` used for, because you've declare your `checkConn()` at your `futureBuilder`.
I just can suggest you to solve your problem with these 3 option that you can pick bellow:

#### 1. Remove your await in initState

just delete your `_checkConn = checkConn();`

#### 2. Remove your setState() during your build Widget

from my experience, the error like I write below can happen when you call `setState()` during the building widget.

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

so, I assume that you have some `setState()` inside your build without any event.

#### 3. Use if mounted

`await` syntax can make some error when you build it in `initState()`, you can use 1 of some `StatefulWidget()` **lifecycle** to build it, that is `mounted`.